# Use LVM for extending a folder’s size by merging it with a folder on an external drive

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd, lvm

I basically have this folder where I need to store 1.5 terabytes. However, I only have 900 gb on my internal drive. How do I configure a folder using LVM so that it tries to fill up internal, then moves files to the external drive once it runs out of internal drive space?

Note: I want it to regular check if the internal drive is free; if it still has free space, I want the computer to keep moving external drive files from a designated folder back to the internal drive until internal storage fills up.